# Laravel delete model custom return

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

Okay so I'm trying to delete a model and then return a `response()->json([...])`. For some reason when I delete the model it always returns `NULL` whatever I do.

Here is the function in the `User` model that is used to delete the given user.

```
/**
 * @return bool|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse|null
 * Delete user
 */
public function deleteUser()
{

    // If the admin deletes his own account we need to check if there is another admin. There must exists at least 1 admin
    if ($this->user_id == auth()->user()->user_id && (auth()->user->hasRole('admin'))) {
        if (User::whereHas('roles', function($query) { $query->where('id', 1); })->count() <= 1) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'There must be another admin if you remove your own user.'
            ]);
        }
    }

   if (!$this->delete()) {
       return response()->json([
          'success' => false,
          'message' => 'Could not delete user!'
       ]);
   }

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'User was deleted successfully!'
    ]);
```

Is there something I'm missing when I want to return a custom response?

***EDIT***
Here is the controller method

```
public function postDelete(User $user)
{
    $user->deleteUser();
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting the ability to delete a User in more than one place in your application i.e. do you have multiple places where a User can be deleted ?

Comment: Nope. Only from user management in the dashboard currently.

Comment: In that case, why are you putting this sort of logic in the Model instead of just keeping it in the controller?

Comment: Good question. I don't know why I do it, it looks better for me this way, but is it bad practice? Should the checks/validation be in the controller?

Comment: Yeah, I would definitely recommend just keeping it in your controller. Are you able to show the controller method where you're calling `deleteUser()`?

Comment: Sure, ill edit the post. Gimme a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing the `return` in your controller method:

```
public function postDelete(User $user)
{
    return $user->deleteUser();
}
```

Comment: Oh wow.. Always the smallest things... Thanks for noticing and the tips for keeping some of the logic in the controller. Got some changes to do. :D

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball It's alright. Glad I could help! :)